# How do I know that which server processes my custom workflow in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Workflow Timer Service is running on all the servers(2WFEs + 2APPs), How do I make sure that my custom workflow(SPD) is running on the specific server? I was trying to find the workflow logs(ULS) and could not find on any of the servers.

3/28/2014 2:49 PM   Error   System Account  Coercion Failed: Unable to transform the input lookup data into the requested type.

I do understand that it is failed due to lookup issue however do not know which properly leads to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that files from _layouts\ folder are stored separately on every server. 
For example deploy a text file Test.txt to http:\yoursite_layouts\yourproject\Test.txt and put different content of this file to each of the servers (edit the file manually in c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS). 
Then make your workflow to add Test.txt file to a library and see what content the file in this library has.
Hopefully you get the concept. You can also use CSS files and have different style applied in the same CSS file on every server.

Comment: good suggestion even though little difficult.

Comment: Well, you don't need to do it exactly that way. The idea is to use the resources from layouts folder. Your workflow can for example display an image from _layouts folder on the page. Edit this image on each server (draw a number 1,2.. on the picture). Then run the workflow and see what number is presented. Or find out your way of using _layout folder.